# HID descriptor maximum

Tags: hid

Hi I'm wanting to make a HID dj controller with a Ardiuno uno as the core.
I've had some success with using the unojoy usb gamepad project
http://code.google.com/p/unojoy/

I have read elsewhere that the maximum size for a HID report is 64Bytes so I intend to have
48 analogue inputs at 8 bit resolution and 128 binary inputs (48*8)=384+128 =512b or 64B,

Is this many inputs possible/plausible?

Also is there any open source code for some kind of HID device with this great a many inputs? (or similar)

Thank you.

SELF ANSWERED, Yes it is possible, I am struggling to understand how I should write the report descriptor.